# how to add delay in python webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am new to web scraping and python I got stuck with a website which loads the price after a certain time the page is loaded I have no idea how to pull the data from that web site [this is the sample link](https://www.northcoastelectric.com/157299/Category/PowerFlex-520-Family-Options-&-Accessories)
is there any module to pull the data after the website is loaded I am currently using Beautiful soup
and my script is like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.northcoastelectric.com/157299/Category/PowerFlex-520-
Family-Options-&-Accessories'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
products = soup.find_all(id="getchangemode")
# print(product)

for product in products:
    product_details = dict()
    product_details["Main link"] = url
    image = product.find(class_="prodImage").img["src"]
    product_details["Image Link"] = image
    cate = soup.find(class_="cimm_pageTitle").get_text().strip()
    product_details["Category"] = cate
    path_tag = soup.find(class_="cimm_breadcrumbs").stripped_strings
    path = (" ").join([j.strip() for j in path_tag])
    product_details["Path"] = path
    additional_info = []
    for i in x:
        additional_info.append(("").join([j.strip() for j in i.stripped_strings]))
        print(additional_info)
        product_details['Additional_info'] = additional_info
        print(path)
        vend = product.h4.get_text().strip()
        print(vend)
        product_details["Vendor Description"] = vend
        print(product_details)
        brand = product.b.get_text().strip()
        print(brand)
        product_details["Brand"] = brand
        addinfo = product.p.get_text()
        print(addinfo)
        product_details["Additional Info"] = addinfo
        price = soup.find(class_= 'priceLeft')
        print(price)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please format your code

Comment: In statement `for i in x:` what is `x`

Comment: try with [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: sorry for the unformatted codes I used jupyter notebook so while copy pasting the code it went wrong and x is x = soup.find(class_= 'sessionDesp').find_all('li')